# Physicaloid возвращает ответ разбит на части, как исправить?

Tags: java, android, controller, микроконтроллеры

При получении команды от контролера ответ получаю разбит на части, разрывает как то рандомно:

Вот что получаю:

```
com.physicaloid.tutorial5 V/OTBET -﹕ [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
com.physicaloid.tutorial5 V/OTBET -﹕ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 39]

com.physicaloid.tutorial5 V/OTBET -﹕ [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
com.physicaloid.tutorial5 V/OTBET -﹕ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 39]

com.physicaloid.tutorial5 V/OTBET -﹕ [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
com.physicaloid.tutorial5 V/OTBET -﹕ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 39]
```

[image: рваные ответы от контролера]
***Цветами выделил ответы***

Вот полный лог: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/43f1uSck)

В чем может быть проблема ??

Comment: Рискну предположить что проблема в том, что вы ожидаете того, что не нужно. Разбиение потока данных на части при работе с COM-портом зависит от реализации софта и случайных факторов, поэтому хотеть "одна отправка - один прием" категорически не стоит.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, отправка идет в цикле, но рвет на части он не только данный ответ, но и те что имеют размер в 8 байт

и как бы я не изменял скорость роботы цикла или тому подобное, это не даст результата.

Это нужно смотреть в драйвере, но где и что менять я еще не разобрался, у меня UART FTDI

Comment: Я еще раз повторю: разбиение на части зависит в том числе от случайных факторов.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов - посмотрите здесь https://toster.ru/q/244940#comment_838630
мне кажется я на верном пути )

Comment: Вам и там написали что вы хотите ненужного. Ну ковыряйтесь, потратите несколько месяцев - может сами поймете.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а что тогда просто склеивать ответ до кучи и работать уже с ними ?

Comment: П.С. у меня не одна отправка один прием, а отправил жду ответ, получил ответ дальше послал и так всегда